# Attempt to charge recurring fee 2 failed

Tags: ubercart

Attempt to charge recurring fee 2 failed.I am getting this error when i want to charge via developer a/c authorize.net. Normal payments going well but recurring is the porblem..Any idea to fix this error..D7 i am trying.....

Answer (score 1):

Authorize.net renewals cannot be tested while your authorize.net account is in "Test Mode". I have tested and confirmed this. It will work if you set the account to live mode.

You can see the relevant discussion here: http://drupal.org/node/812922